# Large Create-React-App Bundle Size - Optimized Production Build

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, create-react-app

Looking to deploy a `create-react-app` configuration on Heroku with the following buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

I've noticed I have a larger build size of **425 kb** after being gZipped and my **website is really slow on initial load**

**Are the following steps decent enough measures to reduce the bundle size? (ie. The best bang for buck precations). If not, what would else would you recommend?** - *I have not done this yet:*

1. Code Split where I can and use [React Loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) (and maybe use
   [react-universal-component](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component))
2. Ensure I load only the required modules (ie. `import { map } from 'lodash/map';`).

---

**Other Solutions I'm reluctant to do**

- Use [Preact](https://github.com/developit/preact) as I don't want to break things :)
- [Two Quick Ways To Reduce React App’s Size In Production](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a) - It looks like this would require ejecting, and I'm curious if it's worth it?

Namely it adds the following:

`new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), //dedupe similar code 
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), //minify everything
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()//Merge chunks`

`Build time Gzip` - Which I think is already done by `create-react-app`

---

**My Source Map Explorer** - Once again, will try and take down Firebase, remove Lottie, and import only necessary modules

[image: I will ensure I remove some modules through specifying better...]

**Heroku Build Logs**

```
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
-----> Configure create-react-app build environment
       Using `NODE_ENV=development`
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       up to date in 14.708s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       Skipping because NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'false'
-----> Build succeeded!
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
=====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
       Using existing `static.json`
       Enabling runtime environment variables
-----> Build succeeded!
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
=====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
       Using existing `static.json`
       Enabling runtime environment variables
> journey-client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_127125dc8ce0d7d71d8f78fe226cf544
> npm run build-css && react-scripts build
> journey-client@0.1.0 build-css /tmp/build_127125dc8ce0d7d71d8f78fe226cf544
> node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/
Wrote 2 CSS files to /tmp/build_127125dc8ce0d7d71d8f78fe226cf544/src/
Creating an optimized production build...
File sizes after gzip:
  495.27 KB  build/static/js/main.b1129bd4.js
  18.05 KB   build/static/css/main.e2b6d04c.css
The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:
  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
=====> Detected Framework: Static HTML
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
-----> Installed directory to /app/bin
Using release configuration from last framework (Static HTML).
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 92.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v94
```

Comment: Any progress? I'm curious as well.

Comment: @MathieuK. Nothing yet. I think this is "normal". I think best practice is to be very judicious about which packages you include. Also look into code-splitting. I'm not sure how it works on the back end, but WebPack will automatically split your code into separate modules. If you can separate your large packages between the different React Classes which are split -> They will be loaded on the flow as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only use packages that you are required to use. If you have packages of substantial size, only include the modules you require:

   import 'firebase/auth';
   import 'firebase/firestore';
   import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
2. Use something like `Gatsby.js` which handles code splitting for you!
3. Utilize practices like `code splitting` with `next.js`, `react-loadable` or other.
4. Use a Server-Side Rendering Solution

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem , I didn't want to eject my old CRA project.
I did the following steps :
1. Update your React ad React-DOM to the latest versions (16.8.6 in my case) - run 'yarn react@next react-dom@next' (or npm command if using npm)
2. Use the React.lazy and React.Suspense approach to lazy load you libraries and / or components on demand here is a link https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

That's about it, but if you encounter a error using the 'import' syntax , you'll need to use the babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import plugin.

You get the latest react version and hopefully reduced bundle sizes - I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with create-react-app for a large project. I will suggest you set up the react project manually and do require configurational changes for the development and production environment.
There are plenty of resources out there that can help to configure the web-pack that can help to reduce the bundle size for the project.
Here is an example of one of them.

[Two Quick Ways To Reduce React App’s Size In Production](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a)